# Replace php tags in html

Tags: php, html

I made one language file and I included in my `html` code. Like for writing `Student Name`, I DEFINE in my language file as `STN_NAM`, and I am writing in `html` code as

```
<?php echo STN_NAM; ?>
```

codes in my language file is

```
<?php
$nm = array(
    'PET_NAM'   => "Student Pet Name",
    'STN_NAM'   => "Student Full Name",
    'STN_FAT'   => "Father Name",
);

foreach($nm as $key => $val)
    define($key, $val);
?>
```

Always I have to write this common code as `<?php echo xxxx; ?>`. Is there any way to just by writing `{STN_NAM}` it should print full student name.

The result will look like this

```
<td>{STN_NAM}</td>
```

This will help me and many other alot if I can get this....

Comment: On Sackoverflow it makes not much sense to ask *if there is a way*. In programming *most often* there *is* a way, so the answer is yes. What you ask about is commonly called a template engine. Please research first, otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: Ok its fine, I will modify my question to suggest the code.. thanks

Comment: It's possible, but it complicates matters a lot - you'd have to have a real template engine that parses the code for occurrences of `{xxxxx}` and replaces it with the value in question. Ask yourself very carefully whether it's worth the extra complexity.

Comment: Well, what would be interesting to know for example which of the common template engines didn't do it so far for you and why? Related: [Is include()/require() with “side effects” a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7697389/367456) and [Creating a simple but flexible templating engine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5815028/367456)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php variable in html no other way then: <?php echo $var; ?>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150238/php-variable-in-html-no-other-way-then-php-echo-var)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really think you should adopt Smarty template engine as a standard php lib for your projects.

http://www.smarty.net/

```
Name: {STN_NAM}<br>
```

From: [php variable in html no other way then: <?php echo $var; ?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150238/php-variable-in-html-no-other-way-then-php-echo-var)

Answer (score 3):

How about (in a local scope):

```
<?php extract($nm); ?>

...

<td><?= $STN_NAM ?></td>
```

It's still a little repetitive but better. You could also implement a templating system as others have suggested.

Comment: @hakre - Thanks, was trying to find the syntax as I wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not in raw PHP. You can of course use a templating system (written in PHP) to enable this kind of syntax. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org), [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com) and others use that or a similar syntax.