# Modify file-content before including

Tags: php, html, file, templates, include

Is it possible to change some file-contents from a file before including it?

I basically want to make a really simple template system. To do so I just include the templates, which are HTML files being able to contain PHP code.

My problem: 
To make it easier to use I want to replace all `{something}` in the to be included contents with `<?php echo $something; ?>`. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should use the code format in your posts to make them more easier to read. I edited this one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You retrieve the file its contents with for example `file_get_contents`<sup>[manual](https://php.net/file_get_contents)</sup> and then use a regular expression to find & replace placeholders with variables. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5815269/1777956) for a very simple approach.

Do note that there are already a lot of template engines out there. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/) and [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) can all do what you want and more. In fact, plain PHP by itself [can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977529/using-php-as-a-template-engine) as a template engine but there are [arguments against](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engines-in-php) that, too.

Comment: Problem is that I need to execute PHP Code in the template too. Most of the template will only be HTML or those `{something}`s, but the user (Well, me) should have the possibility to add code in between PHP Tags.